# Pandas Datframe: Format certain values of a column to float values with floating point after first digit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having a string-type dataframe column that looks something like this:

```
1.0
0.4
209180
9.0
28048193028
6.0
8.0
```

I would like to format it to look like this:

```
1.0
0.4
2.1
9.0
2.8
6.0
8.0
```

I have tried to remove the floating point and to split the string with a floating point after the first digit but it doesn't work. Any tips on how to solve this?

I have tried to remove the floating point and to split the string with a floating point after the first digit but it doesn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arithmetic with [`numpy.log10`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html) to compute the number of digits, [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) the negative numbers to 0 and [`divide`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.divide.html) accordingly:

```
import numpy as np

s = pd.to_numeric(df['col'])
df['num'] = s.div(10**(np.floor(np.log10(s)).clip(0))).round(1)
```

Output:

```
             col  num
0            1.0  1.0
1            0.4  0.4
2       209180.0  2.1
3            9.0  9.0
4  28048193028.0  2.8
5            6.0  6.0
6            8.0  8.0
```

Intermediates:

```
             col      log10  floor  clip          10^x  num
0            1.0   0.000000      0     0  1.000000e+00  1.0
1            0.4  -0.397940     -1     0  1.000000e+00  0.4
2       209180.0   5.320520      5     5  1.000000e+05  2.1
3            9.0   0.954243      0     0  1.000000e+00  9.0
4  28048193028.0  10.447905     10    10  1.000000e+10  2.8
5            6.0   0.778151      0     0  1.000000e+00  6.0
6            8.0   0.903090      0     0  1.000000e+00  8.0
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['1.0', '0.4', '209180', '9.0', '28048193028', '6.0', '8.0']})
```

Comment: could you also give me a soution where noting is rounded?

Comment: I don't understand your comment ;)

Comment: I mean a version where all values have the floating point behind the first digit but none of the gets rounded, so all digits are visible. Thank you :)